# How to extract individual record from 'DataFrame' object

Tags: python

I am using python Google Finance api to get the data , And here is the exact format in which I am getting the data. But I tried to split the data to get the each individual data but not successful.

```
f=web.DataReader(ticker, 'google', start, end) ## calling the Google Finance Api
print f ### it output the following data 

?Date     Open   High   Low  Close    Volume

2014-02-03  11.52  11.72  11.2  11.23  26594854
```

Can anybody help me, how to get the individual data actually. Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are these two separate strings?

Comment: Not actually they are the same string that is returned by google finance.

Comment: I think `Google Finance` is returning a `'DataFrame' object ` not an `string`

Answer (score 0):

Well as you state that this is a string, you can create a dictionary out of it as follows:

```
s = '''Date     Open   High   Low  Close    Volume
2014-02-03  11.52  11.72  11.2  11.23  26594854'''

a,b = [i.split() for i in s.split('\n')]

result = dict([(i[0],i[1]) for i in zip(a,b)])

>>> print result
{'Volume': '26594854', 'High': '11.72', 'Low': '11.2', 'Date': '2014-02-03', 'Close': '11.23', 'Open': '11.52'}
```

Then, you can do things like:

```
>>> print result['Volume']
26594854

>>> print result['Low']
11.2
```

Comment: I am getting the error `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer .

```
f=web.DataReader(ticker, 'google', start, end)
         try:
              for date, _value in f.iterrows():
                  print _value['Open']
         except Exception as E:
              print str(E)
              pass`
```

It gives me output `11.52`